# HTML/CSS: Empty rectangle

Tags: html, css

I need to make an element that takes up a given amount of space (width) such that I can line up several of them together to make a horizontal bar.  I can get it to work with absolute position, but I have to manually control 'left' to get the bar segments (rectangles) lined correctly, which is becoming somewhat troublesome.  Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this where .rect divs are your boxes:

```
<style>
#container{
  float:left;
  position:relative;
}
.rect{
  float:left;
  height: 50px; /* or whatever you want */
  position:relative;
  width: 50px; /* or whatever you want */
</style>

<div id="container">
 <div class="rect">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="rect">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="rect">&nbsp;</div>
 <div class="rect">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

This would make a horizontal row of .rect boxes corresponding to the width/other css properties of your container.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply float them.

Assuming a vertical stack you can float all inner elements right, give them a `clear: left;` and put them in an outer element that has a fixed width equal to the largest element.

Assuming a horizontal row, just floating them should be enough.